# I have a problem with wine and games

Tags: wine

I have a problem when I run games in Ubuntu system using Wine program
After a period of time, there becomes a problem,
Become a large screen size, and I can not return to a normal situation
However, using a command Unity
And thus lose all the programs that run and Downloads

Comment: Do you mean that the game you're playing suddenly decreases its screen resolution?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what is happening

Comment: Can you please add a little more detail? (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)) Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Wine->Configure Wine*, press **Add application**, then show path for your game (*.exe), after that go to **Graphics** tab and check **Emulate a virtual desktop**

Then enter your default screen resolution (for example, mine is 1366x768, you can see it from Settings->Display and there you will see Resolution). This will make your game to set a default resolution and this will not be changed.

Comment: **@MahmoudMohamed:** Don't thank **Olimjon**!  **;-)** If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the number to the left of this text, turning it into beautiful green.  That's the best "thank you" you can give!